# How to distinguish between mobile app and browser?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova

My question may sound like "already asked", but I cannot find any answer. My problem is :

I have a phonegap app that only display a remote website (that website is responsive and work perfectly on mobile device). So the app is very simple :

```
function onBodyLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        location.href = "http://www.mydomain.com/";
    }, true);
}
```

As you can see this I just a redirection when that app starts. With that method I have no access to phonegap API after the redirection (am I right?).

My question(s) is: is that method the right method? How can I display/hide element on a webpage depending on the webpage is accessed by the app or by mobile browsers?

Thank you so much

Greg

Comment: Try to read the UserAgentfrom the Device asking the website and hide/show the elements via php, or you could set a get param for the request like www.mysite.com?user=app

Comment: you can use browsers useragent field to decide between browsers

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that you are not allowed to do this from Apple.

From the App Store Review Guideline

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may
>   be rejected

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Is there another way to do that?

Comment: To do what ?, you have to be more clear. As stated by rule 2.12 wrapping site in an app is just not allowed. You will need to make a real app not just a wrapper around the existing website.